# Most mature sparse matrix package for R?

Tags: r, statistics, matrix, sparse-matrix

There are at least two sparse matrix packages for R.  I'm looking into these because I'm working with datasets that are too big and sparse to fit in memory with a dense representation.  I want basic linear algebra routines, plus the ability to easily write C code to operate on them.  Which library is the most mature and best to use?

So far I've found

- [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix) which has many reverse dependencies, implying it's the most used one.
- [SparseM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparseM/index.html) which doesn't have as many reverse deps.
- Various graph libraries probably have their own (implicit) versions of this; e.g. [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) and [network](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) (the latter is part of [statnet](http://statnetproject.org/)).  These are too specialized for my needs.

Anyone have experience with this?

From searching around [RSeek.org](http://rseek.org) a little bit, the [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix) package seems the most commonly mentioned one.  I often think of [CRAN Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) as fairly authoritative, and the [Multivariate Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Multivariate.html) mentions Matrix and SparseM.

Comment: I think there's `spam` too. The help says: `Differences with SparseM/Matrix are: (1) we only support (essentially) one sparse matrix format, (2) based on transparent and simple structure(s), (3)
tailored for MCMC calculations within GMRF.  (4) S3 and S4 like-"compatible" ...  and it is fast.` Reverse depends: CollocInfer, esd4all, fields, latticeDensity, LatticeKrig, pencopula, rworldmap, splm

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Matrix is the most common and has also just been accepted R standard installation (as of 2.9.0), so should be broadly available.

Matrix in base:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2009/000499.html

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, Matrix is the best supported and most mature of the packages you mention. Its C architecture should also be fairly well-exposed and relatively straightforward to work with.

Answer (score 1):

log(x) on a sparse matrix is a bad idea since log(0) isn't defined and most elements of a sparse matrix are zero.

If you would just like to get the log of the non-zero elements, try converting to a triplet sparse representation and taking a log of those values.

Comment: oops.  i meant log(1+x) actually.  i guess this doesn't make any sense.  yeah, i do it with the triplet representation, which makes much more sense.