# Decision Tree - Sparse dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree

I have very sparse dataset with huge number of attributes (~12 K features and 700K records) I can not fit it in memory (attribute values are binomial i.e. True/False) ,

As it is sparse I keep the dataset in (ID , Feature) format, so for example I would have the following records : 

(ID , Feature) 
(110 , d_0022) 
(110 , d_2393) 
(110 , i_2293) 
(822 , d_933)  
(822 , p_2003) 
....

So we would have three attributes with true value (d_0022 ; 2_2393 ; i_2293) for the record with ID : 110 and the rest are false (attributes are all distinct values of the attribute "feature")

Is there any software available which implements an algorithm to train a dataset over this kind of dataset so I don't make the WHOLE dataset first ?

(Currently I am using rapidminer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [R](http://www.r-project.org/)'s sparse matrices ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274171/creating-and-accessing-a-sparse-matrix-in-r)) or [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) with [SparseIstance](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/core/SparseInstance.html) (or even [BinarySparseInstance](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/core/BinarySparseInstance.html)). If sparse matrix still doesn't fit memory, you can use [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) and little cluster on Amazon EC2 to run SVD, reducing dimensions of your matrix so that they are ok for normal processing.

I have almost no experience with RapidMiner, but possibly it also has some implementation of sparse matrices.