# Rattle loading String to Vector file from WEKA

Tags: r, file-io, machine-learning, weka, text-mining

I have been using WEKA to do some text classification work and I want to try
out R.

The problem is I cannot load the String to Vector ARFF files created by
WEKA's string parser into Rattle .

**Looking at the logs I get something like:**

```
/Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,

: scan() expected 'a real', got '2281}'/
```

**My ARFF data file looks a bit like this:**

```
@relation 'reviewData'

@attribute polarity {0,2}
.....
@attribute $$ numeric
@attribute we numeric
@attribute wer numeric
@attribute win numeric
@attribute work numeric

@data
{0 2,63 1,71 1,100 1,112 1,140 1,186 1,228 1}
{14 1,40 1,48 1,52 1,61 1,146 1}
{2 1,41 1,43 1,57 1,71 1,79 1,106 1,108 1,133 1,146 1,149 1,158 1,201 1}
{0 2,6 1,25 1,29 1,42 1,49 1,69 1,82 1,108 1,116 1,138 1,140 1,155 1}
..../
```

Any ideas how I can convert this into an R readable format?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried using the `read.arff` command?

Comment: That's the `read.arff` function from the RWeka package. `install.packages("RWeka")` should install it.

Comment: @Spacedman - There's also one in `foreign`, and glancing at the source they don't appear exactly the same. I haven't used either, though, so I can't comment on which is preferable.

Comment: Your right Rattle seems to use the read.arff in the foreign package. Is there anyway to force it to use the read.arff in RWeka? I tried loading RWeka lib and detaching foreign but no luck, R just re-attaches foreign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the result of the `StringToWordVector` attribute filter, it will be saved as a [sparse ARFF](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29#Sparse%20ARFF%20files) file.

You need to check if [Rattle](http://rattle.togaware.com/) supports reading this format. If not, you can apply the `SparseToNonSparse` instance filter, which will convert it to a dense matrix format (file size will be much larger).

*Example:* if the sparse data looks like:

#### sparse.arff

```
@relation name
@attribute word1 numeric
@attribute word2 numeric
..
@attribute word10 numeric
@data
{0 1,3 3,8 1,9 1}
{2 2,5 1,8 1,9 1}
```

it will be converted to:

#### nonsparse.arff

```
@relation name
@attribute word1 numeric
@attribute word2 numeric
..
@attribute word10 numeric
@data
1,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,1
0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

Comment: Thanks this works, however it is very painful to load massive files. ANy work around?

Comment: @NightWol: since the sparse ARFF format is simple enough, you can maybe parse the file yourself in R, and store it in a [sparse matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167448/most-mature-sparse-matrix-package-for-r)